# List of interfaces with uncommon generic type

Tags: java, c#, generics, interface, containers

I know that Java is capable of creating containers of for ex. generic intefaces
without need to specify type. Is this somehow possible in c#?

```
public interface Interface1<T>{
    void ProcessModel(T source);
}

public class Implement : Interface1<ModelClass>{
     .....implementation
}
```

I need to instantiate some container like this one

```
public List<Interface1> temp = new List<Interface1>();
```

Instead of this

```
public List<Interface1<Implement>> temp = new List<Interface1<Implement>>();
```

Comment: Only way I can think of is if the class itself containing the list is a generic class. Otherwise it is impossible, since there's no way to know how big of an allocation needs to be done for said type.

Comment: Or somekind of generic container class that in turn is put in the list. Where the base is non-generic

Comment: There is no interface called `Interface1`. It does not exist. There's only `Interface1<T>`. `Interface1<Type1>` and `Interface1<Type2>` are different types. (As opposed to Java, where *only* `Interface1` exists) One solution is to have `Interface1<T>` extend another (non-generic) interface and make a List of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a generic interface for your container you may simply create a non-generic base-interface which your generic one extends. Now you can put all those dervied instances into your container:

```
interface IBase { }
interface IGenericInterface<T> : IBase { }
class MyClass : IGenericInterface<string> { }

class MyContainer {
    List<IBase> impl = new List<IBase>();

    void Main() {
        impl.Add(new MyClass());
    }
}
```